# Чётные числа в массиве

Tags: java, массивы

Не могу разобраться, как в консоли вывести элементы массива: все чётные числа от 1 до 20. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] a = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20};

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = (i+1)*2;

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас в массиве и так уже *"все чётные числа от 1 до 20"*, нужно просто их вывести, без каких-то дополнительных манипуляций. Или в условии какая-то ошибка, сейчас всё это не выглядит осмысленным. Может, нужно просто вывести все чётные числа до 20? Или отобрать их из произвольного массива?

Answer (score 2):

> как в консоли вывести элементы массива: все чётные числа от 1 до 20

Вот так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] a = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20};

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf( "%d\n", a[i] );
    }
}
```

Или у вас что-то не так либо с задачей, либо с входными данными.

Answer (score 0):

Отвечаю с планшета по этому за синтаксис не ручаюсь

```
For(int=0;i<a.length();i++){
   If(a[i]%2==0)
      System.out.println(a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно вывести все четные числа массива в котором могут быть нечетные числа, можно использовать данный подход:

```
 int [] array = {2, 3, 5, 8, 10, 11, 14, 15, 18, 20};

    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {
        if(array[i]%2==0)
        {
            System.out.println("Index: "+i+"; Number: "+array[i]);
        }
    }
```

Если нужно вывести только числа, то и foreach'ем можно обойтись

```
for (int number : array)
        if (number % 2 == 0)
            System.out.println(number);
```

Вывод:

```
Index: 0; Number: 2
Index: 3; Number: 8
Index: 4; Number: 10
Index: 6; Number: 14
Index: 8; Number: 18
Index: 9; Number: 20
```